# invalid hook call in mobx+react native

Tags: react-native, mobx

I'm new to mobx,

I was told that I can't use directly `rootStore` from `rootStore.tsx`  directly, and I have to replace it with hook, so I've tried to call hook `useStore` from `rootStore.tsx`

but in this case I've got an error **"invalid hook call. Hooks can be called inside of the body"**

my files are:

**rootStore.tsx**

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react'
import { makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx'
import { AsyncTrunk } from 'mobx-sync'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { DayStyle, firstDayStyle } from '../styles/markedDayStyle'


const period: Record<string, DayStyle> = {
  '2022-02-16': firstDayStyle,
}


export const rootStore = makeAutoObservable({
  periods: period,
})

export const trunk = new AsyncTrunk(rootStore, {
  storage: AsyncStorage,
})
export const StoreContext = createContext(rootStore)
export const StoreProvider = StoreContext.Provider
export const useStore = () => useContext(StoreContext)
```

**App.tsx**

```
const App = observer(({}) => {
  const store = useStore()
  const [isStoreLoaded, setIsStoreLoaded] = useState(false)


  useEffect(() => {
    const rehydrate = async () => {
      await trunk.init()
      setIsStoreLoaded(true)
    }
    rehydrate().catch(() => console.log('problems with localStorage'))
  }, [store])

  if (!isStoreLoaded) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <StoreProvider value={store}>
        <PaperProvider theme={store.isDarkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <CalendarScreen/>
          </View>
        </PaperProvider>
      </StoreProvider>
    )
  }
})
```

**CalendarScreen.tsx**

```
const CalendarScreen = observer(({}) => {
  const store = useStore()

  const handleDayPress = (day: DateData) => {
    setModalVisible(true)
    setPressedDay(day.dateString)
  }


  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.screenContainer}>
       <Calendar 
        onDayPress={day => {handleDayPress(day)}}
        />
       <View>
          <ModalConfirmDay modalVisible={modalVisible} setModalVisible={setModalVisible} pressedDay={pressedDay} />
       </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )

)}
```

**ModalConfirmDay.tsx**

```
import { fillMarkedDays } from '../functions/fillMarkedDays'

const ModalConfirmDay = observer(({ modalVisible, setModalVisible, pressedDay }: ModalConfirmDayProps) => {


  const handlePeriodStarts = () => {
    fillMarkedDays(pressedDay)
    setModalVisible(false)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <Modal
        visible={modalVisible}
      >
        <View style={styles.modalView}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePeriodStarts()}>
            <Text>Period starts</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  )
})
```

**fillMarkedDays.tsx**

```
import { rootStore, useStore} from '../store/rootStore'
import { firstDayStyle} from '../styles/markedDayStyle'

const fillMarkedDays = (selectedDay: string) => {
  const store = useStore()
 

  if (selectedDay) {
    store.periods[selectedDay] = firstDayStyle
  }
}
```

when I try to add a new key-value (in `fillMarkedDays.tsx`) to `store.periods` I'm getting this

[image]

how can I fix this or select a better approach to call the store? Thanks everyone

Comment: This part of your code looks fine, are you the problem is there? Maybe it's something else? What if comment out all return value and just return some empty block?

Comment: @Danila you're right. The problem is triggered by the file ```fillMarkedDays.tsx ``` . Could you revise it?

Comment: How and where do you use it, could you post?

Comment: @Danila I'm sorry for being unclear, I added the files and edited ```rootStore.tsx```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) you can't use hooks outside of the body of the function (component), so basically you can only use them before return statement, and also you can't use any conditions and so on. `fillMarkedDays` is just a function, not a component, it has no access to React context, hooks or whatever.

What you can do is first get the store with hook, then pass it as an argument into the `fillMarkedDays` function:

```
const ModalConfirmDay = observer(({ modalVisible, setModalVisible, pressedDay }: ModalConfirmDayProps) => {
  const store = useStore()

  const handlePeriodStarts = () => {
    fillMarkedDays(store, pressedDay)
    setModalVisible(false)
  }
  

  // ...
}
```